# Find and replace unknown middle of the string using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am really not familiar at regex and I cant make expression to find that works.

What I have in file:

```
9;01A6DB91;BC994;TRUE

10;01A6A91A;BC994;FALSE

112;01A6E1DA;BC994;TRUE

2000;0196AC26;BC994
```

- Number is integer before first ;
- Then 8 chars A-z and numbers randomly (MAC adress) then ;
- Sometimes line ends in format "BC994" sometimes in TRUE, sometimes in FALSE

How to write expression to change UNKNOWN 8 chars at 112; line, with known 8 chars?

For example:

Find: `112;??????????`

Replace with: `112;12345678;BC994;`

AND leave TRUE or FALSE if it is there, if not, do not add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(112;)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\b`
- Replace with: `$1NEWCHARS`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(112;)          : Capture group 1 that contains literally 112;
[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}  : 8 characters alpha num
\b              : word boundary, make sure we have not other letter/digit after
```

Replace by group1 followed by `whatever you want`

Comment: Thank you for your code, but it works partially, mac adresses may not always have hexadecimal letters, mac adress of my devices can have numbers only, for example 01912345, and if i do replace with $101912345 from 112;01A7C159;BC991 it leaves me with only this ;BC991 im loosing whole row If i use 01A12345 it is working showing me A12345;BC991  

which is not good but its close

Comment: If you try replacing it with `($1)NEWCHARS`, it should work.

Comment: @TaoStyle
Yes it is working, but i found another "bug"
I have in file 3;MAC_ADRESS and 13;MAC_ADRESS AND 113;MAC_ADRESS if my goal is to change mac adress only on 3; can we change code **not** to accept other numbers partially accomplishing condition, if I accidentally click replace all, and I dont see it, i will make a mess, i will lose adresses of multiple devices.
Regex should have something like ^ for "line start with" ? Can I use that somehow to fixate on one and only row?

Comment: @Orion310591: in this case you only have to start the pattern with `\b` *(word boundary)* or `^` if 3 is at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you mean ^(112;)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\b ?
Ok i got it working like that... thanks all. This will save me a lot of time at work.

Comment: @Orion310591: yes or `\b(112;)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\b` *(make some tests)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I forgot one thing, I wanted to use this as search in files, and I must include ";BC900" numbers in search&replace how to add that part? is there $ sign to "must end line with" ?

Comment: @Orion310591: try to think by yourself, you have actually all informations to solve the problem.